# Opensource Java EE Notifications Framework

Tags: java, frameworks, jakarta-ee, notifications, push-notification

Could anyone please suggest if there is any open source Java EE Notifications framework that meets the following criteria?

- Has REST API/Web Service to accept notification messages from external systems.
- Has a framework for persisting the notifications.
- Has a feature to classify the notification by using multiple meta data entries.
- Has a feature to provide authorization based on meta data.

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestion/recommendation please?

Answer (score 1):

Its a pretty late reply although but in case this helps ---
https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere. Use play as the backend framework -  it uses JPA, Hibernate, restful and on the front layer you can use jquery. Also websockets can be used...

Answer (score 0):

Well, 
a framework is a ready-to-use software component which implements commonly used functionality and provides APIs, contracts, interfaces, etc. Using these, developers don't spend much time to implement the same functionality every time when he/she needs this in his/her project. They implement mainly known problems, for example, the problems addressed by (design) patterns (Enterprise Patterns) like association between Data Mapper - ORM and Hibernate.

Your requirement is a standalone project, a business problem. i am seriously sure about that you can't find any framework which fulfills all of these requirements.

But:
For (restful) web services, message-driven architecture, you can use Spring Framework. To persist your objects, use Hibernate (there are millions of articles how to integrate Spring und Hibernate).  For authorization, you  can use Spring Security (formerly Acegi Security).

Comment: Umm... how does this even start to answer the question?

Comment: the second paragraph would be the answer of the problem actually :-)